# expression in join clause?

Tags: oracle, join, oracle11g

*Oracle tables*

The following query works as `START_TIME_` and `DT.LABEL_DATE_TIME_15MIN_INT` output is like for like.  I have to admit it's the first time I've written a join like this, is it acceptable or is there a more efficient/proper way of accomplishing this?

```
select
  A.ID,
  trunc(A.START_TIME,'dd') + (round(to_char(A.START_TIME,'sssss') / 900) / 96) as START_TIME_,
  DT.LABEL_DATE_TIME_15MIN_INT
from TBL_A A
  inner join DATE_TIME DT 
    on ((trunc(A.IN_TIME_START,'dd') + (round(to_char(A.IN_TIME_START,'sssss') / 900) / 96)) = DT.DATE_TIME_15MIN_INT)
order by A.ID;
```

Reason for approach: `A.START_TIME` is `TIMESTAMP(6)` GMT-5 `DT` table has EPOCH time Keys in GMT with corresponding "Formatted Labels" adjusted to GMT-5.  Instead of converting `A.START_TIME` to EPOCH, adjusting for timezone, and joining on the key I performed the arithmetic to `A` to the correct 15min interval then joined to the label.  Am I missing a really simple solution here?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a more concise approach:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.start_time_,
    dt.label_date_time_15min_int
FROM
    date_time dt 
        JOIN (
            SELECT
                id,
                TRUNC(in_time_start,'dd') + (ROUND(TO_CHAR(in_time_start,'sssss') / 900) / 96) AS in_time_start_,
                TRUNC(start_time,'dd') + (ROUND(TO_CHAR(start_time,'sssss') / 900) / 96) AS start_time_
            FROM 
                tbl_a 
        ) a ON a.in_time_start_ = dt.date_time_15min_int
ORDER BY
    a.id
;
```

But fundamentally there's not much difference. Your join is valid, and you could also put it in the where clause if you wanted to. At this point there's not much you can do to optimize it without structural and applicative changes.